# POST and PATCH operations in ArrayModelField using Django DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djongo

I am using Django 2.2, MongoDb with Djongo. I am facing issues in POST and PATCH API. I am facing three kinds of issues.

1. When performing a POST operation to create a new entry, API fails with error: **Array items must be Model instances**.
2. What is the correct way to refer an instance of Screenplay class in POST API. Is the id of the parent class sufficient?
3. How to perform a update to a specific field in Scene model including a text field in comments?

Following is the code snippet.

**Sample POST API data**

```
{
    "title": "intro1",
    "screenplay": "49423c83-0078-4de1-901c-f9176b51fd33",
    "comments": [
        {
            "text": "hello world",
            "author": "director"
        }
    ]
}
```

**models.py**

```
import uuid
from djongo import models

class Screenplay(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True, default = uuid.uuid4,editable = False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField();
    author = models.TextField();

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author +self.text

class Scene(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True, default = uuid.uuid4,editable = False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    screenplay = models.ForeignKey(Screenplay, related_name='scenes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    comments = models.ArrayModelField(
        model_container = Comment,
    );

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from planning.models import Scene, Comment

class ScreenplaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Screenplay
        fields = ('id', 'title')

class CommentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('text', 'author')

class SceneSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    comments = CommentSerializer();

    class Meta:
        model = Scene
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'comments')
```

**viewsets.py**

```
from planning.models import Screenplay, Scene, Comment
from .serializers import  ScreenplaySerializer, SceneSerializer, CommentSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView

class ScreenplayViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Screenplay.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ScreenplaySerializer

class SceneViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Scene.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SceneSerializer

class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the documentation on [Writable nested representations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations), it will help to dissipate your doubts.